# python base64.b64decode(): Is there any limit to length of input (encoded) string

Tags: python, base64, decode

I am using python base64.b64decode() to decode some string fetched from google using REST API. I am able to decode small chunks but not whole encoded string. I tried string upto 4k length to decode, but full string (of length 21k) is not able to decode.

Is there any limit on length of input to base64.b64decode().

example code

```
import base64
encoded_buffer = "ICAgICAgICAgIC<omitting long string (21k long) fetched from google>"
decoded_buffer = base64.b64decode(encoded_buffer)
```

Comment: what is your example code?

Comment: And what happens when it fails to decode?

Comment: getting nothing. decoded_buffer is empty.

Comment: O_o Jon Skeet and me on the same thread! Its like meeting kanye west of programming :D Mahesh give me your phone number, i'll call you we solve your problem right now! :D

Comment: Back to topic, why do you have human readable character in your buffer

Comment: @user1767754 base64 *is* human-readable.  That's one of its design desiderata.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this problem.  I ran `dd bs=1024 count=64 if=/dev/urandom of=/tmp/bin` to create a 64 KiB file of random binary data, then ran `base64 | tr -d '\n'` and used your Python code to decode it with no issues.  I compared the result to the original and there were no differences.

Comment: Live demo here: http://ideone.com/oUcMg4

Comment: So does it mean there is no limit on the length of input to base64.b64decode()? 

Question is, is there limit or not? if yes, then what is the number?
(after getting this, I can consider that input may be wrong, which I am taking from result of REST query.

Comment: @user1767754 Sorry for adding comment in input buffer.
Human readable characters in code are to read, that is actually information to understand question. The actual string is too long and so I have used sample string here by omitting full length string.

Comment: CHECK the validity of your input string in various online decoders. I have seen similar behaviour in a 95k input string that returned only 4k of decoded result in python 3.5.1 x64. Artificial test strings of similar size were decoded without any problem, though. On-line decoders either produced no data at all, or a full sized decoding with blocks of giberish in between good data. I presume the non-python encoder suffered from a buffer problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the limit depends on the buffer size. If the buffer size is not big enough you will get an error

> SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

In that case try to increase the buffer size

> sock.recv(buffer size) # default 1024